# How to get value of <pre> tag and preserve all the white spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xslt, pre

I am using a `<pre>` tag to preserve white spaces and new lines. I am using `contenteditable="true"` inside the `<pre>` tag so that the user can edit the data.
I want to store the user edited data in a variable in JavaScript while preserving the users input but I am not quite sure how to do it. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks!

`XSL`

```
<pre contenteditable="true"><xsl:value-of select="$txn_desc"/></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.innerHTML` if you want to get the markup inside the tag and use `.textContent` if you only need the text.

```
const pre = document.querySelector("pre");//get the tag
const text = pre.textContent;
const html = pre.innerHTML;
```

To prevent HTML being inserted into the contenteditable element, you can add an event listener for keydown and insert "\n" instead when the enter key is pressed.

```
pre.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode===13){
     document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '\n');
     e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Demo:

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    alert(pre.textContent);
});
pre.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode===13){
     document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '\n');
     e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<pre contenteditable style="border: 1px solid goldenrod;">
Text inside 
  
that is multi
line!
!
  
  !
</pre>
<button>
Get text
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have tried this and the new Line are not getting preserved in the JS var...

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Since what I am trying to do is to pass the values from one screen to another and thats why i am using ```<xsl:value-of>``` to extract the value of the node so that user can modify the data, so i wont be able to provide a proper reproducible example but can you suggest some code which wraps everything inside the pre tag in JS or jQuery while preserving white spaces and new lines?Thanks

Comment: It is something like everytime I am adding a space its adding a new <br></br> and when i am adding a new line its adding a new <div></div>

Comment: I am calling my function using ```<li><input tabindex="6" id="Button5" value="Confirm" class="buttons" name="Button5" type="button" onclick="return fnOnSubmit();"/></li>```. And inside the function ```fnOnSubmit``` i am writing all my JS codes. But ```pre.addEventListener``` is not getting called?